# Asymptotic behavior of Regularized Gamma Function

Tags: integration, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I'm currently working on the regularized gamma function:
$$
\frac{\gamma(x, f(x, c))}{\Gamma(x)} = c
$$

Here, $c\in(0, 1)$ is a constant, and $f(x, c)$ is a function of $x$ and $c$ that satisfies the equation. My primary focus is on understanding the asymptotic behavior of a related expression:
$$
\frac{\gamma(1+x, f(x, c))}{\Gamma(1+x)}
$$

as $x$ approaches 0.

Will this expression converge to a specific constant as $x$ approaches 0?
I attempted using $\gamma(1+ x, y) = x\cdot \gamma(x, y) -y^x e^{-y}$ (which is by integration by parts) and converted the expression into the following:
$$
\frac{\gamma(1+x, f(x, c))}{\Gamma(1+x)} = c - \frac{f(x, c)^x \exp(-f(x,c)) }{\Gamma(1+x)}.
$$

The expression is lower than $c$, and I suspect that this will converge to 0 as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x,c)=0$. Now using [this value for gamma regularized $Q(a,z)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/03/01/01/0002/) and $\frac{\gamma(x+1,f(x,c))}{\Gamma(x+1)}=P(x+1,f(x,c))=1-Q(x+1,f(x,c)),\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}P(x+1,f(x,c))=1-Q(1,0)=1-1=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $0<c<1$. By Lemmas $1.1$ and $2.1$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.07234.pdf), we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x,c)=0 \quad\text{ and }\quad \lim_{x\to 0^+}(f(x,c))^x = c.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ +  } \frac{{(f(x,c))^x \exp ( - f(x,c))}}{{\Gamma (1 + x)}} = c.
$$
Therefore, your original expression does indeed converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you!! It was helpful